# Trying to initialize Facebook login in flutter, "No android key hashes configured"

Tags: android, flutter, facebook

I am trying to implement Facebook login using the flutter_facebook_auth package. I already created a Facebook app and configured my app according to the guidelines here:
https://facebook.meedu.app/docs/5.x.x/android

I already converted the sha1 hash to base64. But when I try to add a new Android platform in the Facebook developers interface, it "saves" and then I don't see the platform anywhere. I also tried to use "Quick Start" but the installation does not go beyond the first page. I thought it saved it somewhere anyway, so I run my app. I still get the error "No Android key hashes configured. Configure your app key hashes at - " - as if Facebook just did not save the hash that I gave it. Is it possible there is a bug in Facebook? What could I have done wrong?

*Yes, I've throughly searched previous SOF questions.